# How to disable a text area or mat-form-field

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular (4) + Angular Material and Reactive Forms for my Form Field. How can I disable that? I tried to google for things like **disabled="true"** or something like that. May can you show me the right syntax? That must be easy. Thanks!

my example:

```
<mat-form-field class="xxx-form-full-with">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="My description" formControlName="xxx"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: All depend what you want and how you set it easiest way is `[disabled]="disabled"` . And then change `this.disabled` in true or false.
But you show to much limited code to give a propper answer.

Comment: any solution? i have the same problem

Answer (score 66):

With reactive forms `[disabled]` will not work. 
You need to set the disabled status on the formControl instead:

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  xxx: [{value: 'someValue', disabled:true}]
})
```

Also remember when doing this, this field will not be included in the form object e.g when submitting. If you want to inspect all values, disabled included, use:

```
this.myForm.getRawValue();
```

Comment: Creating the form group input with it as disabled does the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

Since you are using `ReactiveForms (formControl)` you should use

`this.formGroupName.disable()` to disable all the group form or

`this.formGroupName.controls[controlName].disable()` for a specific formControl.

Likewise, if you would like to enable the control again, you could use:

`this.formGroupName.controls[controlName].enable()`

Comment: This is pretty neat and practical way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 13):

Both @dmarquina and @AJT82 provided working answers.
(Although i like dmarquinas answer better)
You can also try:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Some Label</mat-label>
    <input type="text" matInput formControlName="disabledFiled" readonly>
</mat-form-field>
```

Notice the: **readonly** notation.

**Update:** 

Be aware that this can be a **security issue**. As Jnr posted in the comments: 
*Right-click, view source, remove readonly, and you got yourself an editable field again.*

(thanks for the valuable input Jnr!)

Comment: Much better approach since readonly doesn't change the color of the text. +1

Comment: Right-click, view source, remove `readonly`, and you got yourself an editable field again.

Answer (score 6):

You can use disabled property as hardcoded property to your textarea element

```
<textarea disabled></textarea>
```

Or you can bind it to a method in your component class to disable it dynamically based on some condition.

```
[disabled]="getDisabledValue()"
```

**In your .ts file**

```
getDisabledValue() {
  //your condition, in this case textarea will be disbaled.
  return true; 
}
```

Comment: I am confused. Like the things I googled, it's not working. I still can change the values. Any idea why? So the problem is maybe made by a different reason.

Comment: This will not work inside form try another solution like the first one

Comment: it's better to use readonly  if the disabled is not working

Answer (score 5):

Complementing answer of the @poderoso_mike, readonly can be used as `[readonly]="true | false"`.

It's have worked to me using Angular Material 9.

Comment: Confirmed working, note it is on the input, not the mat-form-field: `<mat-form-field ... ><input matInput formControlName="myFieldName" [readonly]="isReadOnly">`

Answer (score 3):

```
<ng-container  *ngFor="let filter of filterSet">     
<mat-form-field appearance="outline"  class="w-11/12">
                  <mat-label>{{ filter.name }}</mat-label>
                  <input
                    matInput [readonly]="filter.enteredValue!==''"
                    [formControlName]="filter.key"
                  />
                </mat-form-field>
</ng-container>
```

[readonly] attribute will help in disabling the form-field.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know to disable a textarea field is to just add the "disabled" attribute into it. like so `<textarea disabled></textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
formControlName: [{value: 'someValue', disabled:true}]
```

This will work but make sure if you have that field is in read-mode, then  while submitting form it will exclude the control with disabled flag. So you won't get value which you patched to that form field.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an issue where I am disabling all of my reactive form fields when I initialize my form like this:
`if (!isEditMode) {this.editForm.disable();}`.

Every input was disabled except for the textarea input. I got around this issue by performing the above code example after I have fetched the data and have patched the form.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31098130)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying my possible answer to the above question

```
 this.formGroupName.controls.controlName.disable();
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML part

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="anything 
       [formControl]="selectedInput" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Code behind

```
function(){
    this.selectedInput.disable();
}
```