# How to disable a text area or mat-form-field in the same HTML (Angular 9)

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I am using Angular 9 with angular Material Reactive Forms. I want to disable the fields, but without using the disabled status on the formControl, just only using HTML instead of programmatically in ts.

My Html:

```
<form name="nameForm" [formGroup]="nameForm" fxLayout="column">
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50" class="m-4">
        <input matInput name="startTime" formControlName="startTime" placeholder="{{'DATE.START' | translate}}"  type="date">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="30" class="m-4">
        <input matInput name="period" formControlName="period" placeholder="{{'TITLE.PERIOD' | translate}}"  type="number" step="0.1">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field fxFlex="20" class="m-4">
        <input matInput name="range" formControlName="range" placeholder="{{'TITLE.RANGE' | translate}}"  type="number" step="0.1">
    </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

My ts:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.nameForm = this.createNameForm();

... some code ...
}

private createNameForm() {
      return this.formBuilder.group({
          startTime: new FormControl(this.startTime, []),
          period: new FormControl(this.period, []),
          range: new FormControl(this.range, []),
      });
  }

... some code ...
```

I came across this doubt because some questions like this one ([How to disable a text area or mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571466/how-to-disable-a-text-area-or-mat-form-field)) has programmatic answers, and I would like to know if it can be solved using exclusively the Html. I know `[disabled]="true"` does not work, but maybe with a different directive?.

I hope it's clear enough and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think [readonly] = true works?

Comment: You can bind the property `[disabled]` but this is explicitly discouraged by Angular. It is recommended to use `formControl.enable() / formControl.disable()`. A warning message will appear if you use `[disabled]`

Comment: you can also use a directive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute (but really is not "only html")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the disabled directive is not valid for the input (it would work with a select or text-area for example ) but to disable the input we can use the ***readonly*** directive

```
[readonly]="true"
[readonly]="method()"
[readonly]="variable"
```

Although, if you need to disable it, another solution would be

```
[attr.disabled]="true"
[attr.disabled]="method()"
[attr.disabled]="variable"
```

I've tried both and they work :)

Comment: I use ```[readonly]="true"``` and it works for me, thanks. Also, I use ```[style.color]="booleanVariable"``` to change the appearance and make it more reactive.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried both the `[disabled] = 'true'` and `[readonly] = 'true'` for the textarea.

Only `[readonly]` property works well in all the cases in angular.