# How do I disable mat-form-field with a conditional value?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-material

This is my code:
<mat-form-field [disabled]="isDisabled">
Which gives me the error:
Can't bind to 'disabled' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-form-field'.

UPDATE:

This is how I solved it. In my case, I actually needed to disable the whole form rather than just the single field.

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="myForm">
    <mat-select formControlName="myControl">
        <mat-option>my first option</mat-option>
        <mat-option>my second option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

JS:

```
//declare the form
myForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        myControl: ['']
    });
    this.myForm.disable();
}

// use the enable and disable methods to toggle between states
if (myCondition) {
    this.myForm.enable();
}
else {
    this.myForm.disable();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable a text area or mat-form-field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571466/how-to-disable-a-text-area-or-mat-form-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your form is reactive then the above `<mat-form-field [disabled]="isDisabled">` will not work.

You need disable it using `this.formGroupName.controls[controlName].disable()`
conditionally.